# Version disparity in hibernate core & annotation jars

Tags: hibernate

```
<hibernate-core.version>3.6.5.Final
<hibernate-annotations.version>3.5.6-Final
```

Why is there a version disparity on the final version of the above hibernate jars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Hibernate 3.6.0, `hibernate-annotations` were merged into `hibernate-core`, so you don't need to include `hibernate-annotations` separately any more.

Comment: Major /facepalm.  How did I not realize this?  Thank you from 2.5 years in the future.